# Is there a path from OpenSCAD to WebGL?

Tags: linux, conversion, javascript, webgl, openscad

tl;dr version, Does a software path exist to convert from openscad input to render on a website via webgl?

What I'm trying to do is display [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/) created designs uploaded via post on a LEMPy driven website; this is currently done by outputting to a static png image.

I would like to render one of [openscad's export formats(wikibooks)](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Using_OpenSCAD_in_a_command_line_environment#Export_options) and convert for display in javascript/webgl through some software path available via linux batch. CPU and RAM are relatively unconstrained but no GPU available.

I've looked into CopperLeicht, but it requires CopperCube output which would require windows or wine. FOSS is preferred but not required.

*edit*: I found [three.js has converters](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/converters/fbx) for fbx, dae, obj, and 3ds formats which might be helpful as one of the last steps.

Comment: OpenSCAD is going to get obj format Soon (TM). There are probably STL converters by now (2015).